# Lambda layer in Keras with keras.backend.one_hot gives TypeError

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to train a character level CNN using Keras. I take as input a single word. I have already transformed the words into lists of indices, but when I try to feed it into `one_hot`, I get a `TypeError`.

```
>>> X_train[0]
array([31, 14, 23, 29, 27, 18, 12, 30, 21, 10, 27,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0], dtype=uint8)
>>> X_train.shape
(2226641, 98)
```

But when I try to create my model like this:

```
k_model = Sequential()
k_model.add(Lambda(K.one_hot, arguments={'num_classes': 100}, input_shape=(98,), output_shape=(98,100)))
k_model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='valid'))
```

I get `TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64`.

It's obviously not making it to a point where X_train is even read, so where is it getting a float value?

I would like to have an instance shape of `(98, 100)`, where 100 is the number of classes.

I can't fit the entire dataset in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a cleaner solution that would achieve the same result, how about:

```
k_model.add(Embedding(num_classes, num_classes,
                      embeddings_initializer='identity',
                      trainable=False,
                      name='onehot'))
```

You are essentially embedding things, it would make more sense to use one with fixed weights. It also gives you the flexibility to make the embedding trainable in the future.

Comment: I now get an error when I attempt to train saying `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected onehot to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (742214, 98)
`

Comment: I also don't see anything about `weights` in the `Embedding` docs. Do  you have any reference for this?

Comment: Unfortunately it is part of the base [Layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/bf1378f39d02b7d0b53ece5458f9275ac8208046/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L54) class and not explicitly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Do you have any suggestions about the new error?

Comment: try adding `input_length=98` I didn't realise you were using fixed length.

Comment: If you're willing to stick with me, the repo is [here](https://github.com/sbendl/Word2VecCNN/blob/master/ML.ipynb)

Comment: The Embedding outputs (samples, 98, num_classes) but your Y data is 2d (samples, 98) that is why the target is not matching, you are not processing the input yet and expect it to predict the target.