# Keras Conv3D Layer with Discrete Values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a model that will learn features of a 3D space. Unlike image processing, the values of the 3D matrix are not continuous; they represent some discrete value of what "material" can be found at that specific coordinate (grass with value 1 or stairs with value 2 for example).

Is it possible to train a model to learn the features of the space without interpolating in-between values? For example, I don't want the neural net to deduce 1.5 to be some kind of grass stairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use one-hot encoding, which represents categorical values as arrays of zeroes with a single value set to one. This means that grass (id = 1) would be `[0, 1, 0, 0, ...]` and stairs (id = 2) would be `[0, 0, 1, 0, ...]`. To perform one-hot encoding, look into keras' `to_categorical` function.

Further reading:

- [one-hot encoding tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/)
- [one-hot preprocessing using `to_categorical`](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical)
- [one-hot on the fly using an embedding layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50446946/2846923)

Comment: Ok this make complete sense. Now, is there any tricks to reduce the data density? Having a 3D bitmap was already kind of expensive in storage. Now this means that I will have a 4th dimension to encode this data to booleans. I can always use a byte to encode 8 coordinates, but maybe there's a better, more clever trick to it?

Comment: @sturcotte06 Are your storage problems in your RAM or GPU memory? If you one-hot on the fly with an embedding layer, then your RAM usage won't change. If you're having problems with GPU memory, then you can try reducing your batch size. Another thing thing to try would be using a normal embedding layer with a smaller embedding vector size (as opposed to a non-trainable identity embedding with a size equal to the number of categories in your input data).

Comment: I don't know yet! I just assumed that if I have a space of 1000x1000x1000 with one byte per coordinate, I'd have 1G per datum, so I'm trying to figure out how I can tackle this issue beforehand. The solution is easy for long-term storage of datasets (compression), but I'm not sure how this can work out in tensorflow.

Comment: @sturcotte06 That is an absolutely massive size for each sample. Unless you have a special plan that I don't know about, I think input data memory should not be your main concern. I'd recommend first trying your idea in a _far_ smaller space, e.g. 100x100x100 (99.9% reduction in volume!). Once you prove that your concept works there, _then_ you can start thinking about how to scale it up to 1000x1000x1000.

Answer (score 1):

As any categorical model, this should be a "one-hot" data.

The "channels" dimension of your data should have a size of `n-materials`.

- Values = 0 mean there is no presence of that material
- Values = 1 mean there is presence of that material

So, your input shape will be something like `(samples, spatial1, spatial2, spatial3, materials)`. If your data is currently shaped as `(samples, s1, s2, s3)` and has the materias as integers as you described, you can use `to_categorical` to transform the integers to "one-hot".

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure if this is what you are asking for, I would imagine that t after the bottleneck of the convolutional network, one would typically use a flatten layer and then the output goes to a dense layer. The output layer, if using sigmoid activation will give you probabilities for each of the classes which have to be one-hot encoded, as others have suggested.

If you want the output of the network itself to be in discreet values, I suppose you can use some sort of step-wise activation function in the output layer. However you have to take care that your loss remains differentiable throughout the network (which is why such activation functions are not available in keras). This might be of interest: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7370